# Mongoose: how to implement pagination?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination, mongoose

I can't find anything about this. Obviously to fetch a next page you'll want to use .skip and .limit, but how do I find out if there IS a next page? Basically computing `has_next_page (boolean)`.

In raw mongo you can do `cursor.hasNext()` to see if there's another page.

I can only think of two ways to do it with mongoose:

1. `.limit(pageSize + 1)`

   Then return only `pageSize` results, but use that last one to
   determine if there's another result or not.
2. `.count()`

   Fetch a count for the query and see if it's greater than `pageNum * pageSize`.

The first seems hacky and second looks very inefficient (counts are expensive, right?), is there no better way to do this?

Comment: I think you should use first approach initially i was using second approach but now i am using first approach, also why did you mentioned that first seems hacky what's hacky about it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1st solution is OK if you don't want to show number of pages but you need to get the count if you want to get number of pages `numberOfPages = count/numberPerPage` so you will run count() at least once at beginning so you query "or more if you want to be update with this information while user use paged data {I'll ignore this for simplicity if it is critical for you please comment here and lets discuss it}".

so the first query will take sometime here a link about issue on MongoDB about count performance telling that they make improvements for this method https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752 .